# Is this face shield ESD safe?

Tags: esd

I just picked up a face shield for in person labs and was wondering if it is ESD safe. In this scenario I'd be wearing a ESD strap, but it seems like the plastic is isolated with foam and an elastic strap. Attached is a picture of the shield and it's claim of "Anti-Static". I'm not sure if anti-static refers to dissipative or the flat prevention of an electrical charge. Below are pictures of the face shield in question.

[image]

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwPR2.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, they are not. I do not believe that anti-fog ESD safe label either.

Comment: There is no "standard" facemask, so asking a question like this about facemasks **in general** really makes no sense. As with most similar questions here the best advice is **read the datasheet**.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The "datasheet" here is the implementation standard (https://www.chinesestandard.net/PDF.aspx/GB14866-2006), which doesn't mention anything concerning ESD. And the material used is specified as 100% PET (edited to add picture), which I know is used in antistatic bags. That coupled with the "Anti-Static" tagline sparked the question.

Comment: Try rubbing it against your hair to see if it makes your hair stand up. On the other hand, are you sure it needs to be static safe? Maybe it is OK since it is entirely composed of dielectric material and not likely to actually touch any electronics.

Comment: Technically not ESD safe. How far away will it be from boards and components?  One foot or more, probably OK.

Comment: @mkeith Good idea, I rubbed against my cat's fur (my hair is a bit too thick) and fur stood up. Cat was mildly confused yet somewhat pleased with the experiment.

Comment: @Mattman944 I'm not too concerned either, I was more just curious based on the anti-static line and the fact that shield may used for in more ESD prone lab settings in future. For my current work it poses minimal concern.

Comment: If someone would like to post the comment findings as answer I will gladly accept it, otherwise I will later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I have determined that this face shield is **not** ESD-safe. Most convincing evidence was that when the shield was rubbed on fur, a charge was accumulated and stored.

Comment: I'm not certain this is a relevant test, or what you are trying to prove. What esd testing standards have you researched that applies to equipment intended to be worn on technician body? Why invent an ad hoc test when there are plenty of standards out there that can be referenced.

Comment: @crasic am not sure it is a comprehensive or perfect test. But it is certainly a relevant test. Rubbing plastic on hair or fur is a way to test if a material is capable of triboelectric charging. ESD safe plastics are formulated to reduce or eliminate triboelectric charging. Thus the definitive property of ESD safe plastics is being tested. I guess what is missing from the test is any quantitative measure of charging. It is more binary (yes/no) and subject to the judgement of the observer.